# Открытие третьей активити при запуске приложения

Tags: android, activity

Всем привет!
Пишу приложение с тремя активити. В первой ввожу имя пользователя, во второй пароль, после которого, в случае успеха открывается третья активити. Задача состоит в том, что при запуске ранее закрытого приложения, должна появиться сразу третья активити, если ранее было введено имя пользователя. У меня в третьем активити высвечивается вместо имени высвечивается null.
Вот часть кода первого активити:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);

    connectionClass = new ConnectionClass();
    edtuserid = findViewById(R.id.edtuserid);
    btnlogin = findViewById(R.id.btnlogin);

    btnlogin.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
             switch (v.getId()){
                case R.id.btnlogin:
                    saveUser();
                    break;
                default:
                    break;
            }
        }
    });
    loadUser();
}


void saveUser(){
    sPref = getPreferences(MODE_PRIVATE);
    SharedPreferences.Editor ed = sPref.edit();
    ed.putString(SAVED_USER, edtuserid.getText().toString());
    ed.commit();
}

void loadUser(){
    sPref = getPreferences(MODE_PRIVATE);
    String savedUser = sPref.getString(SAVED_USER, "");
    edtuserid.setText(savedUser);
    if (!savedUser.equals(null)){
        Intent intent = new Intent(LoginActivity.this, WelcomeActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
}

@Override
protected void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    saveUser();
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Передавайте имя с помощью intent

```
Intent intent = new Intent(LoginActivity.this, WelcomeActivity.class);
intent.putExtra(NAME, savedUser); <== Добавьте эту строчку
startActivity(intent);
```

В принимающей активити получите значение из `intent`:

```
String name = getIntent().getStringExtra(LoginActivity.NAME,""));
```

Почитайте подробней, например, [здесь](https://startandroid.ru/ru/uroki/vse-uroki-spiskom/67-urok-28-extras-peredaem-dannye-s-pomoschju-intent.html)

И измените условие `if (!savedUser.equals(null))` на `if (!savedUser.equals(""))` иначе у вас оно не будет срабатывать.